# Closing a WKWebView and changing ViewController with Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm getting to grips with Swift 4 and Xcode.

I can't figure out how to close a WKWebView after it has been opened!

I am using it to display a PDF document, and have added a Navigation Bar with a 'Done' button.

I have figured out how to got to close it and go to the Root UIViewController, however I want it to go to a View Controller called 'DocumentsViewController'.

Below is the code I am working with, however I believe the line I am trying to fix is: 
`let doneItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.done, target: nil, action: #selector(selectAction(_:)))`

With selectAction being:

```
@objc func selectAction(_ sender:UIBarButtonItem) -> Void {
    //print("Select Clicked")
    self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I've spent hours trying to figure this out! How can I make it so when I click the done button it closes the WKWebView and goes to the 'DocumentsViewController'?

```
@objc func selectAction(_ sender:UIBarButtonItem) -> Void {
    //print("Select Clicked")
    self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: pdfTitle, withExtension: "pdf") {
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(urlRequest as URLRequest)
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

    let navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: 44))
    self.view.addSubview(navBar);

    let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "");
    let doneItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.done, target: nil, action: #selector(selectAction(_:)))

    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneItem;

    navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false);

    // Get height of status bar (iPhone X introduced a new status bar)
    let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
    // Initialize the frame
    webView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: statusBarHeight, width: view.bounds.maxX, height: view.bounds.maxY)
    // Set background color of status bar (optional)
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 248/255.0, green: 248/255.0, blue: 248/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add your new view to the navigation stack...

```
@objc func selectAction(_ sender:UIBarButtonItem) -> Void {
let newViewController = DocumentsViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
}
```